# Stop Web Configuration Inheritence with Azure Virtual Web Application

Tags: web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web application project and deployed it to Azure.

In the `web.config` file for this application, a number of `<assembly>` elements appear in the `<system.web><compilation>` element.  Specifically, these assembly entries point to DevExpress assemblies but they could really be anything.

I have also created a Web API project that is deployed as a virtual application under the web application.  It looks like the `<assembly>` entries are being inherited from the configuration of the web application.  The Web API project does not use these assemblies and throws an exception stating that they cannot be loaded.

As a temporary workaround, I have manually copied over the assemblies to the bin folder of the Web API application.  However, this is not a permanent solution.

I have tried *clearing* the assembly entries in the Web API configuration (using the `<clear />` element).  I have also tried *removing* the entries (using the `<remove>` element).  Neither of these worked.

What is the *best* way to stop this inheritance form occurring?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this official [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance:

**ASP.NET application root directory > Web.config**

> The Web.config file for a specific ASP.NET application is located in the root directory of the application and contains settings that apply to the Web application and **inherit downward through all of the sub directories** in its branch.

**ASP.NET application subdirectory > Web.config**

> The Web.config file for an application subdirectory contains settings that apply to this subdirectory and inherit downward through all of the subdirectories in its branch.

I assumed that you could leverage [Location Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to achieve your purpose. Also, there is a blog about [Settings and Virtual Directory Inheritance](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Aug/11/IISASPNET-Settings-and-Virtual-Directory-Inheritance), you could refer to it.